# VB.NET - Reusing code in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, design-patterns

There is some code in an ASP.NET web application code behind class that I want to reuse in a VB.NET WinForms application.  Please see the code below from the code behind (ASP.NET web application (not website)):

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        MsgBox("button1.click")
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the code behind:

```
Imports WebApplication1

Public Class TestClass
    Public Shared Sub Test100()
        MsgBox("button clicked on page")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1

    Public Event BellRings(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Public test As String

    public Shared TestMethod()
      MsgBox("Test Method was called")
    End public

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim d As WebApplication1._Default = New WebApplication1._Default
            AddHandler d.button1.Click, AddressOf Form1.TestMethod
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I realise that it would probably be better to create a service layer, which both clients use, however I am wandering if the above is even possible? i.e. is it possible to add an event handler in a WinForm for an event in a web application i.e. button.click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could potentially get away with this through the creative use of partial classes and referencing the code-behind class from the winforms app.

However, that would be a very fragile implementation. For example, if you wanted to provide the same functionality through a menu or want to change the button control to a third-party vendor's control that does not have the same signature as the winforms control or vice versa.

A much better approach, even without the service layer, would be to move the common functionality into a class that is shared between the two applications and is simply called from the event handler.

Yes, you will have to define event handlers in both apps, but that is a trivial amount of code and also allows you to perform platform-specific error handling (for example, in the web app, you may want to show the exception through a javascript alert while in the winforms app, you may want to show it through a msgbox).

Comment: Thanks.  +1.  Can you clarify what you mean by: "even without the service layer".  What you have written seems to imply a service layer.

Comment: Also, I have asked a question about using different patterns (to avoid doing what I suggested in the OP).  In case you have time, the question is here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/mixing-fowlers-patterns

Comment: Sorry. To clarify, what I meant is sharing the actual code files between the applications, not implementing another application that provides the functionality independently to both applications. In Visual Studio, you can add a reference to a code file by selecting Add Existing Item... from the Project menu and then clicking the down arrow next to the Add button and selecting Add as Link. This way, you have the exact same code in both apps that, when changed in one, will be automatically changed in the other.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Thanks.  Did you get chance to look at my other question?